# Как дожидаться await асинхронно для List<Task>, чьи задачи уже запушенны

Tags: c#, async-await

Начал разбираться с async/await, понял принцип работы, но столкнулся со такой проблемой:

```
/// <summary>
///  эмитирует файл для загрузки
/// </summary>
public class LoadingFile
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int TimeLoad { get; set; }

    public LoadingFile(string fileName, int timeLoad)
    {
        FileName = fileName;
        TimeLoad = timeLoad;
    }
}
```

В классе ViewModel два списка: Список файлов которые нужно загрузить и список уже загруженных файлов.

```
        #region Constructors

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        //файлы для загрузки. с разным временем скачивания
        LoadingFiles = new List<LoadingFile>
        {
            new LoadingFile("1", 2000),
            new LoadingFile("2", 200),
            new LoadingFile("3", 2000),
            new LoadingFile("4", 100),
            new LoadingFile("5", 50),
            new LoadingFile("6", 70),
            new LoadingFile("7", 1000),
            new LoadingFile("8", 2000)

        };

        //Загруженные файлы.
        LoadedFiles = new ObservableCollection<LoadingFile>();
    }
    #endregion
```

Команда WPF которая запускает процесс скачки

```
       /// <summary>
    /// команда WPF
    /// </summary>
    private Command _load;
    public Command Load
    {
         get
         {
              return _load ?? (_load= new Command(async () =>
              {
                   try
                   {
                        var tasks = LoadingFiles.Select(file => LoadFileAsync(file)).ToList(); //запустим все задачи асинхронно и сохраним их в списке задач

                        foreach (var task in tasks)          //хоть задачи и выполняются асинхронно но результатов дожидаемся синхронно.
                        {
                             var result = await task;
                             LoadedFiles.Add(result);
                        }

                        MessageBox.Show("Загрузка завершена");
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                   }
              }));

         }
    }
```

асинхронная задача по скачиванию.

```
        private async Task<LoadingFile> LoadFileAsync(LoadingFile file)
    {
        var res = await Task<LoadingFile>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(file.TimeLoad);
            return file;
        });
        return res;
    }
```

ИТОГО: хочу добиться параллельного скачивания, т.е. чтобы в список скаченных файлов попадали сначала файлы с малым временем скачивания а не по порядку 1,2,3,4...
В моей реализации var result = await task; заставляет обязательно дождаться скачивания первого файла, хотя многие другие файлы с меньшем временем скачивания уже скачаны и помешаются в список мгновенно, после скачки первого.
Но мне нужен правильный порядок: т.е. все таски параллельно дожидаются await и когда дождались помешают результат в список.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такое:

В UI-коде:

```
async Task DownloadFileAndShow(LoadingFile f)
{
    var res = await LoadFileAsync(file);
    LoadedFiles.Add(res);
}
```

И запускайте все эти задачи:

```
var tasks = LoadingFiles.Select(file => DownloadFileAndShow(file));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Ну или просто упакуйте всё в асинхронную лямбду:

```
await Task.WhenAll(
    LoadingFiles.Select(
        async file => LoadedFiles.Add(await LoadFileAsync(file))));
```

---

(это если я правильно понял: вам нужны результаты в порядке загрузки, правильно?)

Comment: Отлично спасибо огромное асинхронная лямбда помогла, код понятен оказалось все просто!!

Comment: @Aldmi: Пожалуйста! Асинхронные функции так и устроены, чтобы всё получалось просто.