# c# асинхронное выполнение методов

Tags: c#, .net

Мне нужно постоянно пинговать около 400 машин и при это м чтобы другой функционал программы работал. Пишу так :

```
Task<IPStatus> tstTask(Apteka apt)
{
    return Task.Run(() => {
        return apt.ping();
    });
}

async void tstDispRes(DataGridView dvg, List<Apteka> list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        dvg[4, list[i].numPrint].Value = await tstTask(list[i]);
    }
}
```

и после по таймеру вызываю

```
   t2.Start();
   t2.Interval = 1000;
   t2.Tick += (o, v) =>
   {
       tstDispRes(dataGridView2, arrayOfApteka);
   };
```

с асинхронностью все в порядке, но как мне сделать многопоточным это дело? Читал что при создание Task он заносится в пул потоков и выполняется как в отдельном, но почему то это не заметно. Направьте что почитать. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: [Thread](https://habr.com/post/126495/)  надо для многопоточности.

Comment: обернул вызов в thread, и прога начала тормозить, чем это может быть обусловленно? доступом к одним и тем же данным с разных потоков?

Comment: какой вызов Вы обернули?

Comment: @NewView не запутывайте новичка...

Comment: Вот тут есть ответ на ваш вопрос: [Как дожидаться await асинхронно для List<Task>, чьи задачи уже запушенны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/427442/178779) (но это не дубликат!)

Comment: Честно говоря я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в многопоточности. Рискну предположить, что проблема как раз в асинхронности. Await не создаёт потоки, а лишь передает управление интерфейсу, пока вызываемый метод не выполнится. В вашем случае вы каждый Task вызываете и ждёте, то есть у вас в цикле программа через await запускает Task, а после ждёт его выполнения, после чего только переходить к следующему элементу цикла. Нужно в цикле без await создать список Task с нужными параметрами, а после все добавить в ThreadPool.

Comment: Помешайте все задачи в коллекцию и вызывайте Task.WhenAll или используйте класс Parallel

Comment: `выполняется как в отдельном, но почему то это не заметно` - в чем отдельном, что не заметно и как вы определили, что оно не заметно?

Comment: @John прав, это собственно так и происходит. А thread естественно имеет оверхед на запуск и объём памяти, при большом количестве потоков может и притормаживать, нужно оптимизировать вызовы по количеству thread.

Comment: Я предполагаю что метод Run добавляет задачу в пул потоков и выполняет ее в отдельном потоке, или я чет не так понимаю?

Comment: `метод Run добавляет задачу в пул потоков` - да, `и выполняет ее в отдельном потоке` - задача будет выполнена в каком-то из потоков в пуле

Comment: т е чтобы мне выполнить задачу в новом потоке, мне нужно `new Thread(() => {await tstTask(list[i]);}).Start();` по циклу?

Comment: для начала если вы к кому то обращаетесь, пишите его ник. Например, если обращаетесь ко мне - пишите @tym32167 В противном случае я не получу нотификацию и не узнаю о вашем сообщении.

Comment: Далее, вы и в Task.Run() отправляете задачу на выполнение в отдельном потоке. Давайте поясню разницу. Task.Run() - ставит задачу в пул потоков. То есть, например, если в пуле потоков 10 потоков, то максимум 10 задач будет обрабатываться одновременно. То есть это многопоточность, но вам не надо создавать потоки, так как потоки уже созданы за вас и находятся в пуле потоков.

Comment: Но если вы используете `new Thread()` для каждой задачи, то это создаст для каждой задачи новый поток. То есть для 400 задач создаст 400 потоков. Но 400 потоков будут работать очень медленно, так как при работе с потоками есть 2 очень медленные операции: создание потока и переключение между потоками. А при 400 потоках переключений между потоками будет так много, что потраченное на это время заметно увеличит время работы вашег алгоритма

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы я вам посоветовал.

Напишем в каком виде нам надо получить пинг, например

```
public class PingResult
{
    public long RoundtripTime {get;private set;}
    public IPStatus Status {get;private set;}

    public PingResult(long roundtripTime, IPStatus status)
    {
        this.RoundtripTime = roundtripTime;
        this.Status = status;
    }
}
```

Далее, допустим, сам метод для пинга

```
static async Task<PingResult> Ping(string host, int timeout = 2000)
{
    var ping = new Ping();
    var result = await ping.SendPingAsync(host, timeout);
    return new PingResult(result.RoundtripTime, result.Status);
}
```

Заметье, что метод Ping - асинхронный. То есть когда я его буду вызывать - не важно, сколько потоков я задействую, ожидание все равно сделаю асинхронным. То есть пока буду ждать результатов пинга процессор не будет занят вообще.

Вызывать такой код довольно просто

```
var hosts = Enumerable.Repeat("www.google.com", 100).ToArray();
var tasks = hosts.Select(x=>Ping(x)).ToArray();
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
foreach (var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine($"{result.Status} - {result.RoundtripTime}");
```

Что тут происходит: сначала я создаю коллекцию из 100 хостов. Потом я запускаю 100 тасков для опроса хостов. Замечу, что эти таски не выполняются в пуле потоков, так как эти таски работают с сетью, то то, чего они ожидают (ответ по сети) процессора вообще не касается. Далее я асинхронно ожидаю, когда все созданные таски завершатся - это ожидание тоже не занимает процессор. И, в конце, я перечисляю результаты.

Comment: большое спасибо )